# Moving from Access to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, vba, ms-access

I recently moved my application's database from MS Access to SQL Server. And I am really shocked - even though having a good server - most of the `INSERT INTO` queries from front-end Access are horribly slow. Previously while retrieving data I was putting it into temporary access table then after retrieving is completed I did:

```
INSERT INTO permanentTable
    SELECT * 
    FROM tmpTable ;
```

And it took less than 1 minute to move all records to `permanentTable`.

Now with SQL Server it's slightly different - inserting 80 rows takes about 5-6 minutes. And I was trying to optimize the query (it's a table with 40 columns) by removing the index - and it's not fast at all. On the server itself when running the query - it's really fast. What can be wrong? Tried to insert it one by one - and it takes about 5 seconds for a row to insert.

From MS Access I am using ODBC connection with ADODB.conn string and ADODB.execute method.

I am using a code similar to:

```
Sub AdoOdbcExample() 
Dim con As Object 
Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") con.Open _ "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};" & _ "Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;" & _ "Database=myDb;" & _ "Trusted_Connection=yes;" 
con.Execute "UPDATE Clients SET FirstName='Gord' WHERE ID=5;" 
con.Close Set con = Nothing 
End Sub
```

Additionally, this is how my connection string looks like:

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection 
Dim sConnString As String 
' Create the connection string. 
sConnString = "Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};server=nameserver;database=dbname;trusted_connection=Yes;" 
' Create the Connection
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection 
' Open the connection and execute. 
conn.Open sConnString 
conn.Execute (query) 
conn.Close
```

And the query I am running is:

```
CurrentDb.Execute ("INSERT INTO [ODBC;Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};server=serverName;database=dbName;trusted_connection=Yes;].permanentTable SELECT * FROM tmpTable")
```

Comment: Inserting 80 rows from a temporary table should not take 5-6 minutes.  Something else is going on.

Comment: Hello Gordon,

I am using ADODB connection to SQLServer. I think it's the only proper way of doing it? I am not linking the tables to Access directly.

Comment: `"On the server itself when running the query - it's really fast."` - So then what's the problem?  Where else are you running the query and what else are you doing there?  If, when you test the query on SQL Server, it works as expected then clearly the problem is not SQL Server.

Comment: Is your temporary table in Access locally and you are inserting into your remote (linked) SQL Server table?

Comment: Yes J Nevill. I am running it from MS Access as it's a front-end and it's inserting the data that has been prepared by the user to SQL Server. The problem with the query is that it's using a local MS Access table to insert it into SQL Server. It looks similar to:
INSERT INTO [connectionString].SQLServerTable SELECT * FROM MSAccessTable.

But still - when running a normal query without connection strings, when inserting a single row it takes about 5 seconds per single row.

Comment: @Martin1993-03: How much actual data is being moved between these two systems, and how are these systems connected to each other?

Comment: Not really much, David. I am just interacting with SQL Server when I need to insert rows or retrieve some data and as it's still a testing enviroment I am the only user inserting anything.

Comment: How are you running the query? Please show all relevant code. Generic code was posted but actual is more pertinent. It may be your form trigger event or macro/module.

Comment: Updated the query/code.

Comment: Don't put the connection into the SQL. _Link_ the table permanentTable via ODBC and run a normal update query.

Comment: I'd wire up all the tables in Access via ssis and import them at once and be done with it. What is the reason or requirement that calls for you using/connecting with vba code?

Answer (score 0):

Found an extremely fast solution for this problem. Basically it's not good to SELECT everything from Access table and then insert it into SQL Server, it's also very slow to transfer the table, additionally it's not very fast to insert one row after another. The solution for it is bulk update.

Basically I store my strings in

```
Dim sBulkString as String
for i = 1 to n...
     sBulkString = sBulkString & "INSERT INTO...; "
next i
conn.Execute sBulkString, , adCmdText
```